# perform onSaveInstanceState on fragments switching

Tags: android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm creating a calendar event note involving fragment switching. Calendar view and event note view are separated into two fragments. Simply just like:

Calendar<-->Event Note

Calendar can move to Event Note and Event Note can move back to Calendar. However, the problem is I would like to save the date so that the calendar can focus to the date previously selected when return (for now it always focuses on current date as I default).

I have tried onSaveInstanceState() method on Calendar but it does not work or even does not be run...

Currently I'm using an array list to store the fragments so that I can do transaction to those fragments. The function performing 'move forward' and 'move back' is like below:

```
public void fragmentSwitchForward(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = slideMenuActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
}

public void fragmentSwitchBack(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = slideMenuActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I surrender......I use a hashmap to save the temporary values in Application object and then get it.